# how to send realtime updates to client from node js app

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firebase realtime database and firebase firestore in my web app and everytime a user updates their data firebase is sending that data to my server and I want to send that data to client how do it do it because with my current code it is giving me res.setHeader error

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called realtime updates, which use `onSnapshot`.

Here is the relevant tutorial https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

The example there for NodeJS is:

```
const doc = db.collection('cities').doc('SF');

const observer = doc.onSnapshot(docSnapshot => {
  console.log(`Received doc snapshot: ${docSnapshot}`);
  // ...
}, err => {
  console.log(`Encountered error: ${err}`);
});
```